# Prove that $R(T^{*})^\perp =N(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, adjoint-operators

Let V be an inner product space, with T being a linear operator on V. 
How do I prove that $R(T^{*})^\perp =N(T)$? I tried setting $x\in R(T^{*})$ and $Ty\in N(T)$, and set up an inner product = 0 since $Ty\in N(T)$ but just got $T^{*}x\perp y$, and I don't know where to go from there.

Edit: and how could I prove it for a more general case $T:V\rightarrow W$?

Comment: what do you mean by "more general case"? It seems Math1000 has given a proof...

Comment: For when T is a linear function from V->W, rather than just on V. I thought the inner product wouldn't necessarily apply, since it's possible for Tx/Ty to be in a different space, though I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For $T: V \rightarrow W$, we have:
\begin{align}
y\in N(T)&\iff \langle x,Ty\rangle_W=0, \ \forall x\in W\\
&\iff \langle T^*x,y\rangle_V = 0, \ \forall x\in W \\
&\iff y\in R(T^*)^\perp.
\end{align}

Comment: How would I prove it for a more general case T:V->W?

Comment: @George, I have modified the symbols to indicate how it works for the general case $T: V \rightarrow W$. In particular, the proof is not different, you just have to know which space, and what inner product (whether on $W$ or $V$), you're working with.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @ChristopherA.Wong